# My Google Script is sending the same Payload to my endpoint multiple times when I trigger it once

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, monday.com

***Final Edit:   I was working in a sheet another developer had started, and it turns out they created a whole bunch of extra triggers. This being my first Gsheets app, I didnt realize what had happened till I spent more time on it and learned more about triggers Thank you for people who answered and pointed me in that direction.***

I have a Google Sheet script that triggers when the value of a trigger column changes to "Add to Monday".

When I manually change the column to "Add to Monday", the script collects some of the row data from  the row in which I changed the trigger column to "Add to monday".  It then sends it as a payload to my endpoint.

The problem is, is that I can see that my GSheet script is getting triggered 8 times every time I try to trigger it once. As a result it is sending the same payload to my endpoint, leading to duplicate entries being created on in my Monday.com account.

```
function onEditInstallable(e) {
    console.log("function executed");
    var triggerColumn = 15; // Replace with the column number that triggers the action
    var targetUrl = "https://endpoint.url/"; // placeholder endpoint - actual endpoint removed 
  
    var range = e.range;
    var column = range.getColumn();
    var value = range.getValue();
  
    // Check if the edit occurred in the correct sheet, column, and value
    if (
      column === triggerColumn && value == "Add to Monday"
    ) {
  var row = range.getRow();
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
    var payload = {
      "col1": values[0],
      "col2": values[1],
      "col3": values[2],
      "col4": values[3],
      "col5": values[4],
      "col6": values[5],
      "col7": values[6],
      "col8": values[7],
      "col9": values[8],
      "col10": values[9]
      };

      console.log(payload);
  
      // Send the data to Zapier endpoint
      var options = {
        method: "post",
        payload: payload,
      };
  
      var success = false;
  
      try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(targetUrl, options);
        if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
          success = true;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        success = false;
      }
  
    // Temporarily remove data validation
    var validationRule = range.getDataValidation();
    range.clearDataValidations();

    // Update the trigger column with the status
    var status = success ? "Success" : "Failed";
    range.setValue(status);

    // Reapply data validation
    range.setDataValidation(validationRule);
  }
  }
```

I did try to implement "Lock Service", which kind of helped. The app script still is triggered 8 times when I changed change the trigger column in a single row, but only 1-2 entries would be created on monday.com. So 1-2 duplicate entries is better than 8, but still not ideal.   This is the version of my code w/ Lock Service.

```
function onEditInstallable(e) {
  var triggerColumn = 15; // Replace with the column number that triggers the action

  // Check if the edit occurred in the correct sheet and column
  if (e.range.getColumn() === triggerColumn) {
    // Acquire a lock to prevent concurrent executions
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
      if (lock.tryLock(10000)) { // Wait up to 10 seconds to acquire the lock
        processTrigger(e);
      } else {
        console.log("Function is already running.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error acquiring lock:", e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}

function processTrigger(e) {
  var targetUrl = "https://endpoint.url/"; // placeholder endpoint - actual endpoint removed

  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();

  if (value === "Add to Monday") {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
    var payload = {
      "col1": values[0],
      "col2": values[1],
      "col3": values[2],
      "col4": values[3],
      "col5": values[4],
      "col6": values[5],
      "col7": values[6],
      "col8": values[7],
      "col9": values[8],
      "col10": values[9]
    };

    console.log(payload);

    // Send the data to Zapier endpoint
    var options = {
      method: "post",
      payload: payload,
    };

    var success = false;

    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(targetUrl, options);
      if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
        success = true;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      success = false;
    }

    // Temporarily remove data validation
    var validationRule = range.getDataValidation();
    range.clearDataValidations();

    // Update the trigger column with the status
    var status = success ? "Success" : "Failed";
    range.setValue(status);

    // Reapply data validation
    range.setDataValidation(validationRule);
  }
};
```

EDIT:

***Explanation of how I am triggering the event:***

I have a column titled "Automation".  The data I am sending via this endpoint is the row data. When I change the value of the "Automation" column to "Add to Monday", it takes the row data for that row and then sends it as a payload to the endpoint.  See Image below. Currently my code also will change the value of this column to "Success" but that is only for this testing iteration - I will need to make sure the data makes it to Monday.com before changing it to success.

[image of column in G Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0goK.png)

EDIT II:  Triggers for a single event (image)

[screenshot of triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdmZc.png)

Comment: This is probably related to how you're assigining the event onEditInstallable. Can you show us how your bing the event? some event lister?

Comment: You may have created multiple triggers.  Check the listing of your project triggers

Comment: @TalesMGodois I added a further explanation in my original post of how I am triggering the event. It is by changing a column value

Comment: @Cooper I added a screenshot of the triggers - I think I should try taking out the code that changes the value of the column to "success" after it send the data?

Comment: It looks like that you have several triggers with the same handler function which is a very bad idea

Comment: I appreciate the input!  Do you have any general suggestion on how eliminate the extra triggers that i am not intending  to happen?

I do see the code you shared below but I'll have to do some reading to learn what it is trying to do. I apologize if my questions are bad, I've only learned basic javascript and coding in the past few months. Still trying to get my bearings.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createProjectTrigger(handlerName) {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() != handlerName).filter(e => e);//deletes all previous triggers
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(handlerName).forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}
```